# What does 饭圈类 ("rice-ring kind") indicate in 生产这些饭圈类产品?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

> 口号手环、贴纸、小旗子、手幅、胸章……义乌的大小作坊，为4年一度的美国大选，生产这些**饭圈类**产品，正规名称是总统竞选产品。
> <sub>[义乌再次判定：特朗普连任](https://m.k.sohu.com/d/447211719)，2020年04月30日</sub>

The above article discusses Trump-themed merchandise and its manufacture in Yiwu (义乌), comparing the 2016 and 2020 US elections.  I'm struggling with the part in bold:

> [My translation:] Slogan bracelets, stickers, small flags, placards (?), broaches, …… Yiwu's big and small wordshops, for the once-every-four-years US election, produces these 饭圈类 products.  According to regulations [they are] called president election products.

In the above, I don't understand why 饭圈类 ("cooked-rice-roll kind") is used here ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/?sl=zh-CN&text=%E9%A5%AD%E5%9C%88%E7%B1%BB%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81) gives "rice ring products").  It appears to be used metaphorically.

**Question**: What does 饭圈类 ("rice-ring kind") indicate in 生产这些饭圈类产品?

(I found the answer while researching this question.  I thought it was interesting, so I'll self-answer.  I welcome further answers.)

Answer (score 7):

Searching for [`饭圈类`](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A5%AD) in Baidu, I stumbled upon [a Baidu Zhidao artcle](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1803565954867519267.html), which gives an explanation.  The second answer is simpler:

> 饭圈类似粉丝会，大家有共同喜欢的东西，组成了一个圈子。
>
> [My translation:] 饭圈 is similar to "fan group" [粉丝会], everyone has something they commonly like, the group forms a social circle [圈子].

In particular, 饭 in this context does not mean "cooked rice", but is used because the English word "fan" is written in the same way as the (untoned) pinyin for [饭](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E9%A5%AD) (fàn).  Thus, 饭圈 is a "circle of fans".  And in the article about Trump, it refers to products produced for Trump's circle of fans (or Trump's supporters).

Comment: I think 饭 is a transliteration from English word "fan" directly just because of the similar pronounce. Using 饭 to indicate supporters is popular in Chinese entertainment in recent years, so personally I think it is not a serious word that could be used in news reports about political figure properly.

Comment: 饭 pinyin is Fan. 圈 is circle in meaning. (Social circle【圈子】meaning here, ). Also 饭 is what asian eat everyday so they will called then 饭/fan without thinking devalue themselves. 类 is just word meaning (group / similar interest / categories) .

Answer (score 4):

As a Chinese native speaker, I could tell you that 饭 means the same as 粉丝 because of similar sounds, and 圈 means people with similar interests, so 饭圈 means people who love one single idol. However, this word now has a bad meaning, especially means people who is CRAZY to one idol, and ususally do some team behaviors.
Actually 饭圈 is a word, and 饭圈类 means a kind like 饭圈.